# Razor page <select asp-for> submits as null value

Tags: c#, html-select, razor-pages

I'm having trouble getting `<select>` options to submit data with asp-form. I have a value (`examDetails`) in my `TestingController` which is an instance of an `Exam` object. I am working on an Edit page for these exams, which is using an external API as part of a separate project to interact with the database. 
I am able to use input boxes successfully to change the `examDetails` from Edit.cshtml, but once I try using a `SelectList`, the value submitted is always `null`. If I set one of the `SelectList` fields as `[Required]` and have a value selected, when I submit the form it appears that the field is `null`.

```
<form asp-page-handler="Customer" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="examDetails.Type" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="examDetails.Type" asp-items="@FERazor.Controller.TestingController.TypeSL" name="TypeNameTest" 
    class="form-control">
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="examDetails.Type" class="text-danger"> 
   </span>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
</form>
```

And when I inspect the running html page, it does in fact have a value. If I submit this to say `OnPost` as a parameter, I do get the value.

```
<select name="TypeNameTest" class="form-control" id="examDetails_Type">
                <option selected="selected" value="Final">Final</option>
<option value="Midterm">Midterm</option>
<option value="No Exam">No Exam</option>
<option value="Test">Test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The select option should bind to a parameter named `TypeNameTest`. Do you have that as a parameter to your action method or as a property of a parameter?

Comment: I had it as a parameter to my action method which would work, but if I had it as a parameter the value would not pass.
I should have added that on the same page that I have the select I have other fields able to be modified. As an example, this line works to change a value on the TestingController.cs.

    <input asp- 
   ="@FERazor.Controller.TestingController.examDetails.Section" 
    class="form-control" min="1" />

Comment: Just noticed that your form uses GET. Properties in PageModels are not bound in GET requests by default. You have to opt in to binding by adding the `SupportsGet` parameter and set it to true: `[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]`. See more here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding